# Doubts regarding SUMO, VEINS AND OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am having a bit confusion in understanding the difference between
usage of **Veins**, **Omnet++** and **Sumo**.

As per my understanding:

- **SUMO** is to provide road traffic simulation(vehicle movements)
- **Omnet++** is for network simulation (cars can be simulated as a network
  node here)
- **Veins** is it control the above two.

Is that right?

I have read many documents regarding these, but I am unable to
conclude on these. can you please explain me with an example or in a layman terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an up-to-date high-level description (with picture) on https://veins.car2x.org/documentation/

As of Veins 5, the text starts with "Veins, the Open Source vehicular network simulation framework, ships as a suite of simulation models for vehicular networking. These models are executed by an event-based network simulator (OMNeT++) while interacting with a road traffic simulator (SUMO). Other components of Veins take care of setting up, running, and monitoring the simulation." and continues with a more detailed look.